# Can not test something with mocha when I have angular (1.6) as a dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mocha.js, jsdom, babel-register

I want to test a ng-redux reducer wich have angular (1.6) as dependency.
When I run the tests (npm test) with mocha, I get :

```
/data/work/mocha-angularjs/node_modules/angular/angular.js:33343
})(window);
   ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

I tried to add jsdom to provide a fake window. But it still fails during the import of angular with this error :

```
module.exports = angular;
                 ^

ReferenceError: angular is not defined
```

Is there a way to make angular work properly in mocha/babel world ?

I made a small github project available [here](https://github.com/jtassin/mocha-angularjs) which reproduce the problem.

Here is the content of the project :

### Package.json

```
{
  "name": "mocha-angularjs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.6.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.24.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "jsdom": "9.12.0",
    "jsdom-global": "2.1.1",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test mocha src/index.test.js --compilers js:babel-register --require jsdom-global/register"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/jtassin/mocha-angularjs.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/jtassin/mocha-angularjs/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/jtassin/mocha-angularjs#readme"
}
```

### .babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": [],
  "presets": [
    "latest",
  ]
}
```

### The code to test

```
import angular from 'angular';

export default function getFive() {
  return 5;
}
```

### The test

```
import expect from 'chai';
import getFive from './index';

describe('desc', () => {
  it('my test', () => {
    expect(getFive()).to.equal(5);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of someone needs it one day :

I used [angularcontext](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularcontext) to solve the problem.

### package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "angularcontext": "0.0.23",
    [...]
  },
```

### In my test file

```
/* eslint-env mocha */
/* eslint-disable import/no-extraneous-dependencies */
import angularcontext from 'angularcontext';

before((done) => {
  const context = angularcontext.Context();
  context.runFile('./node_modules/angular/angular.js', (result, error) => {
    if (error) {
      /* eslint-disable no-console */
      console.error(error);
      done(error);
    } else {
      global.angular = context.getAngular();
      done();
    }
  });
});

/* eslint-disable import/prefer-default-export */
export const angular = global.angular;
```

The [github project](https://github.com/jtassin/mocha-angularjs) has been updated with it.